# Removing the italicized parts from an APA bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, apa-style, italic

[This journal guidelines](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/%28ISSN%291098-2736/homepage/ForAuthors.html#Style) requires that

> References should follow the APA style, but without any use of italic
>   type

In the [apa6 package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/apa6) some parts of the references are italicized. I'm wondering, is there a *simple* way to change that?

Thanks,

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The apa6 package supports biblatex, apacite, and natbib. The answer will likely depend on which bibliography system you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to redefine locally `\itdefault`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
abc {\itshape abc} \textit{abc}

\begingroup %no itshape here:
\renewcommand\itdefault{n}
abc {\itshape abc} \textit{abc}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```